# How can I use the proxy settings on Epic privacy browser to log on to Facebook?

Tags: windows-7, browser, proxy, privacy, facebook

If I load the Epic privacy browser, go to facebook.com, log in, and then click the proxy button, I can use Facebook for a while. But eventually, Facebook would throw up an error screen, saying that it thinks that my account has been hacked, and then it would make me verify my identity, force me to change my password, etc. I've had to change my password four times in as many days, which is very annoying. Now I turn on the proxy for browsing on to every other site but Facebook.

How can I use the proxy settings on Epic privacy browser to successfully log onto and use Facebook?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem before, but be resilient and eventually Facebook will let you login. But on Epic Browser, it resets cookies, passwords, everything except for bookmarks. Thus you have to sign in again every time when you open Epic Browser.

But if you use the proxy on Google chrome, Chrome will save the passwords and won't delete cookies unless you delete it. Thus, Facebook will automatically sign you in with ease.

To get the proxy on Google Chrome, first go find this extension folder in your Windows/Mac
This would be ~/HiddenReflex/Epic/Default/Extensions/ajmegpdjgmehehagpoiodclfggimmoaa/(version number)

**MAC ONLY** Copy the folder out into the open, such as the Desktop or something.

Open google chrome and go to chrome://extensions

- Turn on Developer mode
- Load Unpacked extension
- Find the version folder and select it.

Boom. you now have Epic browser Proxy on your Google Chrome.

Comment: Interesting, but that doesn't actually answer my question. I don't want to "have Epic browser Proxy on my Google Chrome"; I want to be able to use Epic Browser's "Proxy mode" (which you get by clicking the lock in the address bar, changing it from red to green) so that I can use Facebook with Epic.

Comment: I've had this problem before, but be resilient and eventually Facebook will let you login. However on Epic Browser, it resets cookies, passwords, everything except for bookmarks. Thus you have to sign in again every time. But if you use the proxy on Google chrome, Chrome will save the passwords and won't delete cookies unless you delete it. Thus, Facebook will work on Chrome.

Comment: Edited answer to my previous comment.